# Getting PyDev to recognize the correct Python Interpreter on Eclipse under OS X Lion

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-lion, interpreter, pydev

I have two versions of python installed on my mac running OSX Lion. The first is the default python version that ships with OSX and is found in /usr/bin/python. The version I want to use is the version I downloaded from python.org, and that is installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python. I want to use Eclipse and PyDev using the python.org version as the interpreter. So, in Eclipse, I go to preferences and set the version installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python to be the interpreter.

in a terminal window, if I type: 
$ which python

I get "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python" because I set my $PATH accordingly (modified .bash_profile to permanently do so)

but if I run the following simple script in Eclipse:

```
import os
os.system("which python")
```

the script's output is "/usr/bin/python"

Things I have tried as suggested by other similar posts:

1. tried removing and re-adding the interpreter location
2. tried adding the /Library/.../package-sites to PYTHONPATH

Why isn't eclipse using the interpreter I explicitly tell it to use? Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that os.system('which python') will search for the python in the path, not the one where you're currently running (so, its output is correct).

What you want to use/check instead is **sys.executable** (this attribute will point to your currently running executable).

As for the wxPython issue, which error are you having? (probably another question in stackoverflow thought).

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. sys.executable did indeed confirm that I was running the same python in both the terminal environment and eclipse. Now I know that the error I'm getting with wxPython is due to it not running in 32-bit mode. I will post another question regarding getting PyDev to choose 32-bit mode instead of 64-bit mode. (when I run from the terminal I can specify python2.7-32 as the "executor", just need to find out how to do the same in Eclipse). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eclipse is running the correct python. In your code when running under eclipse which python does not find the python running. Try

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

The issue here is that running a GUI app from the `desktop/dock/folder` does not load your `.bash_profile` and so `which python` does not find your change to the PATH. To change your path for GUI apps you need to edit `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you suggested, but Eclipse is still not using the correct interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I did as you suggested, but Eclipse is still not using the correct interpreter. I ran import sys, print sys.version both from the command line and from within Eclipse but the output is not the same. Eclipse shows 2.7.2, terminal shows 2.7.1. I want to use 2.7.1, and this is the interpreter I point to in PyDev. I also created ~/MacOSX/environment.plist and added the path modifications, and then retried the above. It is very perplexing.

Comment: Interesting - in my Lion /usr/bin/python is 2.7.1 and the latest from python.org is 2.7.2

Comment: Yes, sorry. I got them backwards when writing them in my comment. The whole reason this is important to me is to get wxPython to work. wxPython will not work with Eclipse, but will work on the command line. And I strongly believe I have correctly configured eclipse to use the same version (python2.7_32) as the terminal. So my belief was that if I could get Eclipse to use the same interpreter as the Terminal is using, my problem would be solved. Vim is great, so maybe I'll stay away from the Eclipse route for now. Thanks again for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark here. sys.version will be what eclipse uses to run your code. os.system("which python") will be python found in PATH that eclipse forwarded when running your code. Perhaps if you use PATH tweaks you should set environment variables for running code in Eclipse too.